# What do the exact green areas in the Google Transit overview map mean?

Tags: google-maps, google-transit

Looking at the [Google Transit](http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/#mdy)
overview map puzzles me:

[image: Google Transit overview map]

Is the green colour supposed to mean anything? Participating organisations? If so, how?

Comment: Did you try refreshing your browser to see if the problem persists? I am not seeing it in my browser.

Comment: Persists, perhaps it's a browser/javascript bug (Firefox 11.0), I'll try tonight at home to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 2):

The green areas are defined clickable regions on the map. In the United States and Canada, they are closely aligned to state and province borders. In other parts of the world they follow country borders. When I click on one of the green regions, the map shows a list of participating transit providers in that particular region.

The regions are polygons defined in the file http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/js/transit.data.js

The code that draws the map is in the file http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/js/transit.map.js

Note that the green polygons will not show in Internet Explorer. From `transit.map.js`:

```
// Don't display polygons for IE as they are taking too long to load.
if (!new tmap.utils.Browser().msie) {
  this.map.addOverlay(obj.polygon);
}
```

Comment: Looks like they didn't want to express the [full length of the coast in a vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox)...

Comment: @gerrit If they had been more accurate on the coasts, no doubt the polygons would take too long to load for *all* browsers.

Comment: Of course. But then again, they clearly *do* have a polygon to represent the coastline.